# IOS/Objective-C: Launch UIAlertController from code in subclassed Class in Storyboard app

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertcontroller

Two View Controllers in my app subclass the same class that has common methods.  I would like to launch an alertController (fire an alert) from code in a method of this common sub-classed controller.  But the following code is not launching anything.

Can anyone suggest the right way to point to the subclassed VC to get the alertController to launch?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

View controller1 wired to storyboard subclasses common class as follows:

```
@interface IDManageItemsVC : IDCommonVC <UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

The common VC subclasses CoreVC which has even more common methods for the whole app:

```
#import "IDCoreVC.h"
@interface IDCommonVC : IDCoreVC<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UIAlertViewDelegate>
```

I am trying to fire the alert from code in commonVC (the superclass for the class wired to storyboard) as follows:

```
-(void)fireAlert {

 UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Delete?" message:nil preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

 UIAlertAction* yesButton = [UIAlertAction
 actionWithTitle:@"OK"
 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
 {
 //run code
 }];

 UIAlertAction* noButton = [UIAlertAction
 actionWithTitle:@"Not Now"
 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
 {
 //if chosen run code
 }];

 [alert addAction:noButton];
 [alert addAction:yesButton];
 if ([alert respondsToSelector:@selector(setPreferredAction:)]) {
 [alert setPreferredAction:yesButton];
 }

/* following points to VC not in hierarchy so commented out
    id rootViewController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate.window.rootViewController;
    if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
    {
        rootViewController = ((UINavigationController *)rootViewController).viewControllers.firstObject;
    }
    if([rootViewController isKindOfClass:[UITabBarController class]])
    {
        rootViewController = ((UITabBarController *)rootViewController).selectedViewController;
    }
    [rootViewController presentViewController:alertInvite animated:YES completion:nil]; */
//Following does not do anything
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**Edit:**

Using the following method, with a breakpoint, I visually verified that topViewController is the right one and then presented the alertview from it and it still did not display.  The only thing I noticed is that when I visually examined the alertview, it appears blank with just a slight white curve in the upper left where a rounded corner might be against a white rectangle. So perhaps, there is something wrong with the way I'm creating the alertview.

```
UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];
currentTopVC.presentViewController......... 

- (UIViewController *)currentTopViewController {
    UIViewController *topVC = [[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] window] rootViewController];
    while (topVC.presentedViewController) {
        topVC = topVC.presentedViewController;
    }
    return topVC;
}
```

and instead of `[self presentViewController...`, the following:

```
UIViewController *currentTopVC = [self currentTopViewController];
    [currentTopVC presentViewController:alertInvite animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: alertInvite isn't declared anywhere, so your code won't even compile as it is

Comment: I would look at the console log to see if it complains that you are trying to present from a view controller not in the scene.  It's worth looking at your app in the debugger with the 'Debug View Hierarchy' button (7th icon in the debugger controller area where you play/pause a debug session).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I copied and pasted your code and replaced

```
[self presentViewController:alertInvite animated:YES completion:nil];
```

with

```
[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

and it worked.

This doesn't look like a inheritance issue to me. Are you by any chance calling this method from viewDidLoad: or any method that gets called before the view controller is actually shown? If so, try calling it from viewDidAppear:

Comment: invite was a typo in copying original (which I have changed multiple times).  I changed above.  Code is being called by an IBAction method when someone taps a button so well after View controller is loaded.  For me it it is still not firing although I can put a breakpoint and see that the line is called...I also don't see it in visual debugger

Comment: To reproduce your situation, i created a BaseViewController class and implemented the fireAlert method, then made it public by declareing it in its .h interface file. I then created a ViewController, subclassing the BaseViewController, and putting just a single button in it, with an IBAction that calls the [self fireAlert] method. It works just as expected (no need to conform to any protocol, to test this)

Comment: You were correct, it was working.  The issue seems to be that the alert was executing so quickly and then more code firing that replaced the previous view controller that, I could not see it.  I am not sure why the subsequent code caused the alert to disappear--I have to debug this--but I can now glimpse the alertcontroller for a second or so.

Comment: The code that evidently dismissed the alert was code to dismiss a view controller in the same method intended for the underlying view controller not the alertview.  Looks like you can dismiss an alertcontroller with dismissViewControllerAnimated

Comment: Of course you can. UIAlertController inherits from UIViewController ( https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uialertcontroller?language=objc#relationships )